# Mongoose error problems connecting to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodemon

I am trying to get mongoDB working alongside a phpMyAdmin database and i am getting an error message that i can't workout.

I would be a novice programmer so it could be a pretty basic error i have done somewhere. As far as i know i have installed all the correct dependencies and the error described comes up when i run nodemon server on my console.

```
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

//server for the SQL database
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

var Users = require('./routes/user.routes')

app.use('/users', Users)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port: " + port)
})

// server for MongoDB database

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;

//console.log(uri)

mongoose.createConnection(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.createConnection();
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

const formsRouter = require('./routes/formDatabase.routes');
const adviceRouter = require('./routes/studentAdvice.routes');

app.use('/formDatabase.routes', formsRouter);
app.use('/studentAdvice.routes', adviceRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server backend/server/server.js`
(node:25800) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [Bus]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

***\softwaredevproject\cra-beacon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:543
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^
Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection(
)` is a string.
    at new MongooseError (***\softwaredevproject\cra-beacon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:10:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (***\softwaredevproject\cra-beacon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:543:11)
    at Mongoose.createConnection (***\softwaredevproject\cra-beacon\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:278:17)
    at Object. (***\softwaredevproject\cra-beacon\backend\server\server.js:33:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11 {
  message: 'The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a str
ing.',
  name: 'MongooseError'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of your environment settings, best guess the *ATLAS_URI* setting.

> ATLAS_URI=mongodb://localhost/NAME

Since the error claims that nothing got passed, maybe you forgot to add this setting to your **.env** file?

Comment: The only line i have in my .env file is the one below. Should i have anything else? ```ATLAS_URI="mongodb+srv://JamesGeesus:*********@cluster0-mq74b.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"```

Comment: @JimboGee add the setting above and it should be fine